# Scroll view not working in drag and drop approach. why?

Tags: ios

If we add scroll view to storyboard it will visible on VC, but it not scrolled Why? Can any one please tell me the answer......

Comment: can you provide more details with you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you need to do following.

- Set the `delegate` property of your `UIScrollView`.
- Set its `contentSize`.
- Make your controller to follow the delegate of `UIScrollView` by adding `<UIScrollViewDelegate>`. in your `class` interface declaration.

I hope you have created your `UIScrollView` outlet then add this code in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.myScrollView.delegate = self;
[self.myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH, HEIGHT)];
```